# Show initial state in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a simple redux/react app.  It works fine except it doesn't show the initial state (the users scores).  Grateful for any help!
The reducer is below:

```
  const initialState = [{userScore: 0, computerScore :0}];
 const dataReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case 'USER_WINS':
  return [
    {
      userScore: state.userScore + 1,
      computerScore: state.computerScore

    }
  ]
  case 'COMPUTER_WINS':
    return [
      {
        userScore: state.userScore,
        computerScore: state.computerScore +1
      }
    ]
default:
  return state
}
}
```

And the main class is below:

```
    class Interface extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.computerChoice = this.computerChoice.bind(this);
  this.userChoice = this.userChoice.bind(this);
}

computerChoice () {
  var choicesArray = ['Paper','Rock','Scissors'];
  var computerResponse = choicesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
   return computerResponse;
}

userChoice (userInput){
    var computerInput = this.computerChoice();
    if (
        (userInput === 'Rock' && computerInput === 'Scissors')||
        (userInput === 'Paper' && computerInput === 'Rock') ||
        (userInput === 'Scissors' && computerInput === 'Paper')
    ) {
         this.props.userWinsGame();
    } else {

    }
  }
  render() {
  const value  = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
```

This is where I want to display the scores:

```
         Human: {value.userScore}
         Computer: {value.computerScore}
      <br/>
       <button value='Rock' onClick={(e) => this.userChoice(e.target.value)} >Rock</button>
      <button value='Paper' onClick={(e) =>this.userChoice(e.target.value)} >Paper</button>
      <button value='Scissors' onClick={(e) =>this.userChoice(e.target.value)} >Scissors</button>
      </div>
      )
     }
 }
```

Everything is dispatched here:

```
    const render = () => ReactDOM.render(
<Interface
  value={store.getState()}
    userWinsGame = {() => store.dispatch({ type: 'USER_WINS' })}
    computerWinsGame = { () => store.dispatch({ type: 'COMPUTER_WINS' 
})}
 />,
root
```

)

Grateful for your help- everything works but displaying the initial state!

Answer (score 3):

The main question would be, why is your `initialState` an array? Why your `state` is an array at all? I think you should consider to keep it as an *object*.

Anyways - while your `initialState` is an array:

`const initialState = [{userScore: 0, computerScore :0}]`,

you are trying to set a *value* of *key* as if the `state` would be an *object*.

`userScore: state.userScore + 1,`

`state.userScore` will return `undefined`, plus adding `1` to it, will throw `NaN`.

So as I stated above I would strongly suggest you to use an *object* as your state. However, if you really want it to be an array, use a proper notation then:

`userScore: state[0].userScore + 1,`

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help!  If I set it as an object, so const initialState = {userScore: 0, computerScore :0}; I'm still not sure how to go about accessing the values in it!  Thanks again :-)

Comment: @Nespony I can help you with that out if only you provide me some code responsible for getting the data from the state and displaying it :) Do you map the state to props somewhere?

Comment: Hi there, thank you again!  I've added the relevant code!

Comment: @Nespony You miss mapping state to props. You need to take `userScore` and `computerScore` from the state inside your component. Anyways, `const value  = this.props;` is improper, since `props` probably contain much more fields than only your `state`. It should be something like: `const value = this.props.value`.